# What would be a less-known SSL certificate attribute to look out for?

Tags: ssl, web-server, ssl-certificate, encryption

I'm looking for a simple domain SSL certificate for our company's website and I'm a little confused. A lot of them seems to offer the exact same features, yet at price ranges going from 5$ / year to 50$ / year.

How can a certificate be priced at 10% of a seemingly equivalent certificate? What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

For some reason, this was mistaken as a request for recommendation. English may not being my main language, but still I find it very surprising that there was enough people coming up to this conclusion to close it down.

Anyway, I hope the following can help making this post clearer:

I've compared many certificate providers, which I <strike>didn't and</strike> won't mention, and while I could see different types of certificates (domain, wildcards, etc), I couldn't see a single difference between two certificates of the same kind from two different providers... except the price. And sometimes that difference is huge.

I'm asking if, *at large*, there are subtilities I need to be aware of whenever I must choose a certificate, that could explain this variance in prices. In almost every market, such a variance would explain itself with material quality, company service, warranties, shipping fees and the likes. Here, I simply don't see it and I would like to know if there's anything, other than certificate types, that could explain it.

So again, this is **not** a request for a recommendation, it's just someone being very unfamiliar with the procedure of choosing a SSL certificate who's having a legitimate question about it.

**TL;DR:** Another way to say it would be this: I know little about SSL certificates, I see that specs are type (domain, extended, wildcard, etc), encryption strength and browser recognition, I'm comparing two right now that are equal on each of those specs but priced differently. **Is there another spec I should be aware of?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide where to purchase a wildcard SSL certificate?](http://serverfault.com/questions/599219/how-to-decide-where-to-purchase-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate)

Comment: @MadHatter Now *that's* a legitimate closing reason. Thanks for pointing this topic out to me.

Comment: Some possible criteria: How large you see a chance the CA gets compromised; How many (and how expensive) reissues are possible in case your host gets compromised; How they treat cases when you made a typo on a subdomain and want to revoke free of charge within 2 days; Whether you get support from them in case you have trouble installing the cert/intermediate in your web server; Whether they inform you if they notice your cert has an issue (like weak debian key)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you're forking out for an EV certificate, it's not worth paying more than $10-$15 for a single-domain cert. As long as the CA root/chain is trusted by major browsers, there's very little technical difference between a $5 cert and a $50 cert.

I've been using [SSLMate](https://sslmate.com/) recently, and have found it to be a really slick way to purchase and maintain certificates.

Comment: No need for EV, this is mainly to secure communications on an extranet portal which only our employees will use. I gotta ask, though: how can the more expensive providers even have a business?

Comment: Besides EV, wildcard certs are also a sensible reason one might choose to pay more.  Other than that, a lot of people seem to pay more because it makes them more confident that they must be getting the good stuff.  There's no other advantage really.

Comment: @Crono Many of the more expensive providers are just trolling for suckers and get most of their business via much cheaper resellers. Comodo sells SSL certificates for $80ish, but Namecheap is a Comodo reseller that sells those same certificates for $8ish.